# VB.Net - Getting a string/value of a element html?

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm having a slight issue trying to get string from a element on a website.

**What I'm aiming for**:
Basically i'm trying to get a string/value from a website and make it go into a TextBox.text or label even. 
There isn't much exmaples but I'm not experienced in this area, well in getting/grabbing elements from websites and returning the values into boxes or lables!

But this is what I have so far.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    On Error Resume Next
    'Web String
    Dim ws As New WebClient
    Dim data As String = ws.DownloadString("http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=" & TextBox1.Text)

    'IP
    Dim IP As String = Split(data, "<th>IP Address:</th>")(1)

    IP = Split(IP, "<div style=")(0)
    'If IP = Nothing Then
    'IP = "Unknown"
    'End If
    IPLabel.Text = (IP)

End Sub
```

If any one can help me out on this that would be great!

Thanks in Advanced if anyone can help me out,

Sirmajor

Comment: Side note: you have some vb6 syntax in the above code. Are you get `.net and vb6` confused?

Comment: Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @zaggler : This is VB.NET. He's using some VB6 methods and the `On Error Resume Next` statement, but this is VB.NET due to how the button event is constructed. VB6's button events looks like this: `Sub Command1_Click()`. --- **EDIT:** My bad. I looked it up, and I used to use VB6 but my button events didn't look like VB.NET's, but like what I wrote above. Strange...

Comment: @VisualVincent I clearly understand what hes doing, I was asking him :)

Comment: @zaggler : Yes I know you do, but my point was just answering your question about if it was VB6 or not :). Also, see my edit.

Comment: @zaggler I just grabbed some source I found and fiddled around with it. I know my question is very unclear but all i'm trying to do is find out how to return a string value from  a website and make it return into a label or box.text

Comment: @Visual Vincent HTML parser ? never heard of one =o , any exmaples ?

Comment: Well an XML parser or HTML parser is your best solution. For example .NET has the built-in `HtmlDocument` class. Other options include the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML page is same as `xml`, so you can parse string to `XDocument` object and query that object to find information you need.

```vb
'Dim url As String = "http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=" & TextBox1.Text
Dim url As String = $"http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip={TextBox1.Text}"
Dim data As String = webClient.DownloadString(url)

Dim htmlPage As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(data)

Dim header As XElement = 
    htmlPage.Descendants("th").
    Where(Function(thElement) thElement.Value.Equals("IP Address:")).
    FirstOrDefault()
```

Above is the example of how you can find specific node from xml document. Use same approach to find value you need.

Comment: Getting errors on this , this line:

Dim url As String = $"http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip={TextBox1.Text}"

Comment: +1 Love me some string interpolation! I use $"" all the time now. I know you edited the post, but I'd provide both ways in the answer.

Comment: Still not understanding this at all =/ , You mind fixing the code so it can read that particular line or string from the website ?

I'm tryign to get the returb values of majority of string form this site when it finds the details of the IP. 
http://www.ip-tracker.org/

Comment: @JayMaylott, sorry, based on your code, I am still confusing about what information you trying to retrieve from the webpage. I gave you example how you can handle xml-based data. [LINQ to XML Overview (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt692886.aspx)

Comment: Just need to get the string really but I can't get them as there in tables instead of Divs

So form that site I just need all the info that it gets from the ip: 

Ip:
host:
Address:
ISP;
Region;
City:
Etc etc