# VB.net Get text/string from html element

Tags: html, xml, vb.net

I'm having major trouble trying to get bits of elements and returning the strings. 
I have a few exmaples of trying to get the strings and what not but failing hard.

HTML Phrasing is difficult for me to do so help would be appreciated.

**Explantion of what I need**:

I need to get the strinsg of different elements off this site when entering a IP 
http://www.ip-tracker.org/

I need pretty much all the details but into labels or text boxes.

Or this with xml phrasing
http://ip-api.com/xml/8.8.8.8

So here is the exmaple that i've used so far but haven't got far with it.

**Exmaple 1**:

```
Dim client As New WebClient
Dim ip As String
Dim city As String
Dim Region As String

Private Function GetIp()
    Try
        Dim Page As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=82.16.38.43/")
        ip = Page.Substring(Page.IndexOf("IP Address:") + 80)
        ip = ip.Substring(0, city.IndexOf(" </td") + 30)
        TextBox2.Text = ("IP Address: " + ip)
    Catch ex As Exception
        city = "Unable to lookup"
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```

**To call it**:

```
getViews()
```

Comment: You need to use an XML parser.

Comment: Any exmaples of how to use that ? , i'm a bit rusty here.

Comment: Search Google for LINQ to XML and `XElement`

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553727/vb-net-getting-a-string-value-of-a-element-html

Comment: @Blackwood I guess so , but i'm slowly progressing of what i'm needing but still having trouble grabbing the elements. Div's are fine , I can get them no worries it's just in tables i'm having trouble with.

Comment: @JayMaylott ***please, please*** do not create another question when you already have done so [***here***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553727/vb-net-getting-a-string-value-of-a-element-html).

Comment: I do apologise , just needing help badly here!

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Dim url As String = "http://ip-api.com/xml/8.8.8.8"
    Sub Main()
        Dim query As XElement = XElement.Load(url)
        Dim status As String = query.Element("status").Value
        Dim country As String = query.Element("country").Value
        Dim region As String = query.Element("region").Value
        Dim regionName As String = query.Element("region").Value
        Dim city As String = query.Element("city").Value
        Dim zip As String = query.Element("zip").Value
        Dim lat As Double = query.Element("lat").Value
        Dim lon As Double = query.Element("lon").Value
        Dim timezone As String = query.Element("timezone").Value
        Dim isp As String = query.Element("isp").Value
        Dim org As String = query.Element("org").Value
        Dim _as As String = query.Element("as").Value
        Dim subQuery As String = query.Element("query").Value

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You absolute lifesaver! , it works like a charm , hopefully there is more type of xml version of ip trackers! 

Thank you very much!